# Facing Problem with a Math Function

Tags: javascript

```
 var num1 = "5.54";
 var num2 = "10";
 result = (num1/num2)*100;
```

With javascript the result shows 50. But If I do the math using a calculator I find 55.4 which is correct. Would you please kindly help with the javascript code to make the result 55.4.

...

Hi,I have managed to make it work using parseFloat
example-                       var num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("obtainedmark").value);
                               var num2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("totalmark").value);

Thanks.:)

Comment: You need to learn the difference between interger division vs floating point division.

Comment: @Oded: [There's little distinction in JS](http://jsfiddle.net/AkxdM/).

Comment: i can't reproduce the 50. see http://jsfiddle.net/aa5yX/

Comment: What browser are you checking this in? Just curious if that's your problem. (when friends ask you to use old versions of IE, just say no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parseFloat:

```
result = (parseFloat(num1)/parseFloat(num2))*100 ;
```

edit:

I just checked and it works without parsing as well. The problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Strings can be converted to floats implicitly though, when needs be.

Answer (score 2):

[It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/cgcXj/).

Comment: I'm sad that not everyone will understand how console.log works :(

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a java script function

```
  function disp_text1()
   {
      var num1 = "5.54";
                var num2 = "10";
                result = (num1/num2)*100 ;
                alert(result);

   }
```

i got 55.400000000000006....on calling the function...try it again....